# Problema camera iOS 14.4

Tags: ionic, ios, cordova-plugin

Recentemente a apple lançou uma atualização de versão de seus dispositivos, a versão 14.4.

Ao atualizar meu iPad para está versão, a funcionalidade do aplicativo que eu estou utilizando a camera parou de funcionar. Não abre mais a camera para que eu possa anexar uma foto ao meu aplicativo.

Atualizei o plugin que estou utilizando e coloquei uma tag no config.xml como mostrado neste [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera)

Eu acredito que possa ser a permissão, pois ao entrar em Ajustes > MeuAplicativo > não tem a opção de habilitar a camera...

Segue minhas configurações:

config.xml

IMPORTANTE: Removi algumas tags sobre o Android e referencias de icone e splash screen pq faz diferença aqui

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="29" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="true" />
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Permissao para tirar foto!</string>
    </config-file>
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" overwrite="true" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
        <string>Adicione fotos às solicitações</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" overwrite="true" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
        <string>Adicione fotos aos solicitações</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" overwrite="true" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
        <string>Inclua sua localização nas solicitações</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" overwrite="true" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>Inclua sua localização nas solicitações</string>
    </edit-config>
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-appversion" spec="^1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="^3.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^3.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^3.0.1">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="28.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="^8.1.0">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="^2.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-market" spec="^1.2.0" />
<plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.5.2" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" />
<engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/battery-status": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/market": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/vibration": "4.10.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "b64-to-blob": "^1.2.19",
    "cordova-android": "9.0.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "6.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-update": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-appversion": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-battery-status": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-keyboard": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration": "^3.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-webview": "0.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.4.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "2.8.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic1-star-rating": "^1.2.13",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "iphone": "0.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.9.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.24",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": "^1.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-appversion": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-vibration": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-battery-status": {},
      "cordova-plugin-market": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs camera access",
        "MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs microphone access",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs write-access to photo library",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs read/write-access photo library access"
      }
    },
}
```

Imagem do estado atual:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparei com um projeto onde a camera funcionava e reparei que a unica coisa diferente era o plugin AndroidPermission, no projeto onde a camera não funcionava não tinha este plugin instalado...

Instalei [este plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions), configurei onde precisava, instalei o aplicativo no meu iPad e a permissão apareceu, aprovando a permissão a camera tambem apareceu, resolvendo o meu problema.